# PySpark - Returning a value into a dataframe, if a value occurs on another dataframe where two fields match

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Sorry for the vague title, I can't think of a better way to put it. I understand a bit of python and have some experience with Pandas dataframes, but recently I have been tasked to look at something involving Spark and I'm struggling to get my ahead around it.

I suppose the best way to explain this is with a small example. Imagine I have dataframe A:

```
id | Name    |
--------------
1  | Random  |
2  | Random  |
3  | Random  |
```

As well as dataframe B:

```
id | Fruit  |
-------------
1  | Pear   |
2  | Pear   |
2  | Apple  |
2  | Banana |
3  | Pear   |
3  | Banana |
```

Now what I'm trying to do is match dataframe A with B (based on id matching), and iterate through the Fruit column in dataframe B. If a value comes up (say Banana), I want to add it as a column to dataframe. Could be a simple sum (everytime banana comes up add 1 to a column), or just class it if it comes up once. So for example, an output could look like this:

```
id | Name    | Banana
---------------------
1  | Random  | 0
2  | Random  | 1
3  | Random  | 1
```

My issue is iterating through Spark dataframes, and how I can connect the two if the match does occur. I was trying to do something to this effect:

```
def fruit(input):

    fruits = {"Banana" : "B"}

    return fruits[input]

fruits = df.withColumn("Output", fruit("Fruit"))
```

But it's not really working. Any ideas? Apologies in advance my experience with Spark is very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```python
#sample data
A = sc.parallelize([(1,"Random"), (2,"Random"), (3,"Random")]).toDF(["id", "Name"])
B = sc.parallelize([(1,"Pear"), (2,"Pear"), (2,"Apple"), (2,"Banana"), (3,"Pear"), (3,"Banana")]).toDF(["id", "Fruit"])

df_temp = A.join(B, A.id==B.id, 'inner').drop(B.id)
df = df_temp.groupby(df_temp.id, df_temp.Name).\
    pivot("Fruit").\
    count().\
    na.fill(0)
df.show()
```

Output is

```
+---+------+-----+------+----+
| id|  Name|Apple|Banana|Pear|
+---+------+-----+------+----+
|  1|Random|    0|     0|   1|
|  3|Random|    0|     1|   1|
|  2|Random|    1|     1|   1|
+---+------+-----+------+----+
```

**Edit note:** In case you are only interested in few fruits then

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
#list of fruits you are interested in
fruit_list = ["Pear", "Banana"]
df = df_temp.\
    filter(col('fruit').isin(fruit_list)).\
    groupby(df_temp.id, df_temp.Name).\
    pivot("Fruit").\
    count().\
    na.fill(0)
df.show()


+---+------+------+----+
| id|  Name|Banana|Pear|
+---+------+------+----+
|  1|Random|     0|   1|
|  3|Random|     1|   1|
|  2|Random|     1|   1|
+---+------+------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really helpful! Quick follow up question, would you know how I could count the pivoted field based on values of the column rather than the whole column itself? In the example above I had a few fruits but in the real context I have thousands of values and I'm only interested in a few, would be great to do something like an if statement to count only if the value of the column matched x

Comment: Glad that it helped! Pls check my above update for an answer to your follow up question.